# Peculiar silhouette score is reduced with more clusters

Tags: python, clustering, error, hierarchical-clustering

I am working with Python and a set of sensors. I want to use clustering on them.

To do that I have used hierarchical cluster with average linkage and euclidean distance as:

```
Clustering_Jerarquico=linkage(data_state_normalized, 'average')
```

Now, I want to use the [silhouette score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) to check for the optimal amount of clusters. Inspired by the elbow method, I have generated the following for loop to check for which value of "t" the graph slows down

```
silhouette_index_list=[]
for i in range(100, -1, -1):
    clusters_provisional=fcluster(Clustering_Jerarquico, t=i, criterion="distance") 
    silhouette_avg_provisional = silhouette_score(data_state_normalized, clusters_provisional, metric='euclidean')
    silhouette_index_list.append(silhouette_avg_provisional)
```

I am expecting to see an increase in the index until I arrive at a value of 1 at the distance of 0. However, I see a function which increases until it arrives to a top value and then decreases again. This makes no sense to me. As far as I understand, the silhouette index should go between -1 and 1 from the case in which all the data is in a single cluster until the case in each variable is in it's own cluster.

Am I understanding it wrong or can this be explained by the data itself?

I have cleaned the data using `data_state_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(data_state)`

Comment: Silhouette statistic is an extremum, not an elbow type of clustering index. But anyway - why wouldn't you supply the data and the cluster results to your question? Plus the lineplot if your Silhouette values? This is the sort of question better to ask with a reproducible example in hand.